# Get or fetch API data using Angular (v5) with services and interface?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I am working on Angular with v 5 app. I am doing API fetching and using https://angular.io/guide/http document. But I am unable to see anything in my view.

How can I fix this problem with document provided data?

My folder structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIwtr.jpg

There isn't any bug in terminal:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb7uU.jpg

No issues in console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwRoG.jpg

File: app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ConfigService } from './services/config.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  providers: [ConfigService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

file: config.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Config } from './config';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  configUrl : 'http://localhost:3000/api/get';

  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
    }
}
```

file: dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from '../../services/config.service';
import { Config } from '../../services/config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private configService : ConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  config: Config;

showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe(data => this.config = { ...data });
}
}
```

file: dashboard.component.html

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let config of configs">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">{{config.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

file: config.ts

```
export interface Config {
    name : string
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your API response data?

Comment: You're using `*ngFor="let config of configs"` but there is no `configs` property in your dashboard component. Only one `config` instance.

Comment: @Jeto but that probably would show an error in this case, but yes in code above it's seems like that a problem.

Comment: @Sh.Pavel Yeah calling `showConfig()` at some point would definitely help as well :)

Comment: @Laiso , I haven't tried with this project Anyways Thanks  . Angular v5 official document needs to revamp a lot

Comment: @Jeto , yes . i somehow manage it. angular documents were so misleading

Comment: @Sh.Pavel , thanks anyways. I was looking the way out from angular v5 docs . but these docs are misleading i suppose

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code, that you call showConfig() method.

Maybe you forget to add call to ngOnInit() method?

```
 ngOnInit() { 
   this.showConfig();
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks And I need to add also in
file: config.service.ts 
 getConfig():Observable<Config[]> {
    return this.http.get<Config[]>(this.configUrl)
    }

file: dashboard.component.ts

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.showConfig()
  }

  config: Config;
  
  configs = [];


showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe(data => this.configs = data );
}

.Angular v5 official document is so misleading , i suppose

Comment: @ManishVashisth so, if you get configs[] so yes - it is,  and call your method in ngOnInit method as I have show above.